Redundant phrase on Tour page
The current description on the Tour page reads:

Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for cryptocurrency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Cryptocurrencies such as e.g. Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple, Zerocoin, Dogecoin, Ethereum, and NXT.

[emphasis added]
One of the definitions of e.g. is "such as", so this phrase is redundant.
My vote is to drop the "e.g.". The description would then read:

Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for cryptocurrency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple, Zerocoin, Dogecoin, Ethereum, and NXT.


I've deleted the extraneous "e.g.". Thanks!

Well spotted. I agree, dropping the e.g. would make sense.

Bitcoin and Cryptocurrencies is a question and answer site for cryptocurrency enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Cryptocurrencies such as Bitcoin, Namecoin, Litecoin, Ripple, Zerocoin, Dogecoin, Ethereum, and NXT.

